# How to make this code more idiomatic F#?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I have a function A similar to this which applies a function B to every file in a directory. Each file has a certain number of "entries"; the function B takes the current total of entries as a parameter and returns the number of new entries found in the current file.

Also, I need to count the number of files processed and display this count each time a file is processed. Due to my imperative background, I came up with 2 mutable variables and a for loop.

```
let files = Directory.EnumerateFiles sourceDirectory
let mutable numEntries = 0
let mutable numFiles = Seq.length files
let mutable index = 0
for file in files do
     printfn "done %d of %d" index numFiles
     let numNewEntries = processFile file numEntries
     numEntries <- numEntries + numNewEntries
     index <- index + 1
```

So, a few questions:

- How can I write this in a more idiomatic, functional style?
- Can you explain the advantages to a more idiomatic solution? I'm very
  new to functional programming and sometimes I don't see what's wrong
  with my dirty imperative for loops.

Comment: This would be more appropriate for [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). In any case, where is `fileCounter` declared, and why are you ultimately assigning `unit` to `files`? (Is `files` intended to be a function?)

Comment: Sorry the formatting was misleading and the declaration of fileCounter was missing. I edited the code to fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a more functional example:

```
let files = Directory.EnumerateFiles sourceDirectory
let numFiles = Seq.length files
files 
|> Seq.mapi (fun idx file -> (idx,file)) // Get access to the index in a loop
|> Seq.fold (fun numentries (index,file) ->
         printfn "done %d of %d" index numFiles
         numentries + (processFile file numFiles)
         ) 0
```

By using `mapi` I am able to get access to the index in the loop, eliminating the first mutable variable.  The second is eliminated by using `fold` to keep track of the total number of files rather than a mutable variable.

The main advantage of this is that without any mutable state it is possible to more easily convert the code to running in multiple threads.  Also, as variables are constant, it becomes simpler to reason about the code.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the code which was a bit misleading and missed a declaration: could you update your answer to reflect it? fileCounter (actually numEntries) is not the same as numFiles. numFiles is the total number of files in the directory and is used for printing "done x out of numFiles". fileCounter (renamed numEntries) is the running total of entries found in files.

Comment: With your answer accepted, you should at least make it compilable. ;-] (Hint -- `Directory.EnumerateFiles` does not return an array.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what you're ultimately after is the final value of `numEntries`, then here's my take:

```
let getNumEntries sourceDirectory =
    Directory.GetFiles sourceDirectory
    |> fun files -> (0, 0, files.Length), files
    ||> Array.fold (fun (index, numEntries, numFiles) file ->
        printfn "done %d of %d" index numFiles
        index + 1, numEntries + processFile file numEntries, numFiles)
    |> fun (_,numEntries,_) -> numEntries
```

If all you're after is side-effects in `processFile` rather than the final `numEntries` value, then replace `fun (_,numEntries,_) -> numEntries` with `ignore`.

---

> Can you explain the advantages to a more idiomatic solution? I'm very new to functional programming and sometimes I don't see what's wrong with my dirty imperative for loops.

Besides being subjective, that's rather broad and has been answered much more thoroughly in multiple other answers than I could do here.

Comment: The function actually returns unit: "processFile" does all the useful work as a side-effect (writing entries to disk).

My question isn't about functional programming in general, but specifically this little snippet of code. I'm aware of the general ideas, but I'm trying to get concrete examples to drive the point home. Surely it's not too broad a question to ask why these 7 lines are better code than my 9 lines.

Comment: @Dr_Asik : If you want the function to return `unit`, then replace `fun (_,numEntries,_) -> numEntries` with `ignore`. And even if it's not too broad to ask about this particular code vs. the code you posted, it's certainly subjective, which by definition is not fit for SO. In any case, like I said, there are dozens of answers on SO answering what you're asking, not to mention the thousands of other articles online.